# How do I set up a Minecraft server on a specific port?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I'm trying to set up a game agent and it listens for a server at port 10000. How can I set up a game so that this agent can start interacting in the game?

Comment: [Related] [How can I specify the server port in the client?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/201364)

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the Port in the `server.properties` file, which should exist next to your server executable:

```
server-port=<desired-port>
```

[more information](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Server.properties)